# Fazer quebras de linhas em um texto que vem do banco de dados em uma única variável

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou com dificuldade em inserir quebras de linha no texto que vem como resposta de um select no banco através de uma requisição ajax.

```
$('select[name=tipo]').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('tipo.getTemplate') }}",
        method: "get",
        data: {
            value: value,
            _token: _token
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
            $("#template").val(result[0]['conteudo']); //este é o resultado onde quero quebrar linhas

        }
    })
});

<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label" >{{ trans('app.email')}}<span class="spancolor">*</span> </label>
    <textarea style="height: 200px;" value="" class="form-control" id="template" name="template" placeholder="{{ trans('app.template')}}"></textarea>
</div>

public function getTemplate(Request $request) {
    $value = $request->get('value');

    $dadosTemplate = DB::table('template')
            ->select('template.conteudo', 'template.observacao', 'tipoincidente.observacaoincidente')
            ->join('tipoincidente', 'tipoincidente.id', '=', 'template.idtipoIncidente')
            ->where('tipoincidente.nome', $value)
            ->get();


    return response()->json($dadosTemplate);
}
```

Aqui está o template de email, no qual envio o texto que tem no textarea. Este tesxto esta na variável {{$email}}.

```
<div class="fonte">
        <p>Prezados Senhores,</p>

        <p>{!!$email!!}</p>

        <p>{{$finalizacaodoemail}}</p>


        </div>
```

Código de envio de email

```
$emails = ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"];
                $copias = ["email3@gmail.com"];


            $beautyemail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);

        $beautyemail->send('dashboard.templateemail', ['email' => $template, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'cargo' => $cargo, 'phone' => $phone, 'ramal' => $ramal, 'finalizacaodoemail' => $finalizacaodoemail],  function($m) use ($emails,  $assunto, $copias, $template, $finalizacaodoemail)
            {    
                $m->to($emails)->subject($assunto)->from("email4@gmail.com", "Lorena Dutra")->cc($copias, "email cópia");    
            });
```

Comment: Por qual motivo exatamente você quer inserir essa quebra de linha? As vezes existe forma mais fácil de alcançar o mesmo objetivo. Está tendo problemas com o posicionamento do texto em alguma div?

Comment: Porque o texto que vem no textarea é enviado por email, vou atualizar a pergunta adicioando o template de email que estou usando. Quando enviado por email o texto vai todo junto sem quebras de linha, gostaria que a a cada "." tivesse uma quebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após a primeira resposta acho que entendi o seu problema. Além de exibir o texto formatado no elemento  você também quer que o e-mail seja enviado com o conteúdo formatado. A melhor opção é formatar o conteúdo no back-end (código PHP).

Espero que esse código te ajude:

```
public function getTemplate(Request $request) {
    $value = $request->get('value');

    $dadosTemplate = DB::table('template')
        ->select('template.conteudo', 'template.observacao', 'tipoincidente.observacaoincidente')
        ->join('tipoincidente', 'tipoincidente.id', '=', 'template.idtipoIncidente')
        ->where('tipoincidente.nome', $value)
        ->get()[0]; // Suponho que você esteja usando Laravel, então eu aconselharia a utilizar o método "first()" ver https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

    $template = $dadosTemplate[0];
    $template->conteudo = implode(".<br>", explode(". ", $template->conteudo));

    return response()->json($template);
}
```

Na requisição ajax eu faria dessa forma:

```
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    $("#template").val(result.conteudo);
}
```